# issue with creating a one dimensional array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, operating-system

So the issue is for my project I have to pretty much create an inverse table page for my operating systems class. The TA wrote down some basic code to get started. To create the table, he said the table should be a struct that
* includes metadata such as page size and the number of pages along the translation
* table (that can be a 2-dimensional array, or a one-dimensional array of structs)  so here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 500
struct invTablePage{
    invTablePage page[N];

};

struct table
{
    int numOfPages;
    int pageSize;
    int array[struct invTablePage];
};


void initInverted(struct invTablePage **invTable, int memSize, int frameSize);

int translate(struct invTablePage *invTable, int pid, int page, int offset);

void releaseInverted(struct invTablePage **invTable);
```

however when i compile the code it gives me this

```
error:  expected expression before ‘struct’
error: array type has incomplete element type
  struct invTablePage page[N];
```

I have tried using size of but that doesnt work. Apparently int array[struct invTablePage] can be done but i dont understand how that even is supposed to work if it makes more sense trying to get the size of the struct. As far as array type has incomplete element error, i am not sure about that one if i already declared my struct of type invTablePage so it should be working. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: So what do you think `array[struct invTablePage]` should be good for?

Comment: `struct invTablePage{    invTablePage page[N]; };` Recursion in structure definitions. That's some advanced C right there ;-)

Comment: There are other problems with your code. `invTablePage` is not declared anywhere. Even if it was, it could not be used in its declaration.

Comment: That is supposed to be the translation table. And I will be using it to make an array of those structs. So in struct invTablePage thats where i create an array of those structs. Not sure if that makes sense but that is what the assignment is asking for .

Comment: It does not compile. Which might be what you mean with "doesn't work". But without a [mcve] and all required  information we don't know. See [ask].

Comment: Is this the code your TA gave you? It has some problems. First of all, you have `struct invTablePage` containing a field of its own type, which doesn't work for obvious reasons. Also, the keyword `struct` is missing from that line. Also, the array declaration in `struct table` is wrong because the size of the array needs to be a nonnegative integer expression.

Comment: he only gave us the code starting from where it says struct table all the way to the end . The only thing I did was create the struct invTablePage. The reason i did that was because he declared the array in the struct table as int array[struct invTablePage]; So i thought that ok, he wants us to create another struct called invTablePage and then create the array of structs inside that struct. But of course like you mentioned, you cant declare invTablePage in its own declaration so now i am just trying to figure out the proper way to declare it

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205135/error-field-children-has-incomplete-type-node-2

Answer (score 1):

struct invTablePage{
    invTablePage page[N];

};

You cannot define a structure like this.A structure can have a pointer to it's own type but cannot have a member of it's own type.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking the compiler to create an array of type invTablePage before it has been defined. You need to define:

```
struct invTablePage{
    void* page;

};
```

Then allocate an array for the page member during initialisation:

```
void function()
{
  invTablePage table_page;
  invTablePage* entry;

   table_page.page = (void*) calloc(N, sizeof(invTablePage));

   /* for example to access element index = 3 */
    entry = (invTablePage*) table_page.page[3];
}
```

You'd be better implement a linked list.